# Change PDF Text color in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, .net

I'm looking for a way to programmatically change the text color of a PDF document. I have found several libraries but for now I have found a way to change the background color only. I would appreciate a sample code. Open Source libraries are preferred. Thanks.

Comment: http://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/how-to-set-page-for-printing-pdf-c/ - he seems to get it done through a library called Spire.

Comment: Convert yout PDF to Doc and then change color and again convert to PDF

Comment: @KyorCode I've seen several samples using that library but it seems like it is commercial!

Comment: @Trikks I've found a number of libraries in my searches but I've only used PDFSharp

Comment: What is the source before you have a pdf? HTML? Server data, is it from SSRS?

Comment: @Alireza Noori What is wrong with a recommendation for a commercial library if it solves your problem? If you need recommendations with a particular kind of lincese you must say so on your question.

Comment: @KyorCode I'm modifying existing PDF files. I want to change all texts to a certain color. For instance if it's black, I want to change it to gray.

Comment: Not a programmatic solution but Nitro PDF is good for this sort of thing if it's a one off, if you need to do this on a regular basis then you really need access to the source of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford a commercial tool, [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator) allows you to do this by changing the TextColor and BackColor attributes of the desired [Text object](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Object_Attributes/Drawing_Objects_Attributes/Text_Object_Attributes.htm). This PDF edition library can modify the page content and it will draw the rectangle for you below the text. *Usual disclaimer applies for this suggestion*.

Another possibiity could be to generate bitmaps from your PDF file, using ImageMagic for example, then process each bitmap programmatically appling a color mapping (replacing each color channel by 255-value for example to obtain a color inversion), and then showing the resulting image or generating a new PDF from it. This approach has the disadvantage that the whole PDF will be converted to a raster image, and you will not be able to select text on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to pay for a commercial library. I want to modify PDF files for my personal usage and what I want to achieve doesn't worth paying money for. Currently, using PDFSharp I can change the background color of all pages using the method you described, the color of text objects remains.

Comment: If after some time, no one could suggest a free solution, I'll select this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Alireza Noori Actually, I did not read your question properly, my apologies. See my update and let me know it it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The only problem I have is this: How can I retrieve the existing texts on the document, iterate through them and change their colors?

Comment: Can you provide a sample, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Alireza Noori My wife had this problem yesterday at her workplace, and she came up with a partial solution that I have posted here for you. Maybe it can help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It's not what I was looking for but it is the closest.